# Asp.NET MVC 2 Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to define a route that have **2 optional parameters** in the **middle** of the **URL** the **start** an **end** parameters are digits

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "",
                "Source/Changeset/{start}/{end}/{*path}",
                new {
                        controller = "Source",
                        action = "Changeset",
                        start = UrlParameter.Optional,
                        end = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                        path = "crl"
                    },
                new { start = @"\d+", end = @"\d+" }
                );
```

i tried diferent approaches and none of them worked, i could use some of your help.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

### I manage to solve the problem this way, but it's far from elegant.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "",
                "Source/Changeset/{start}/{end}/{*path}",
                new {
                        controller = "Source",
                        action = "Changeset",
                        start = UrlParameter.Optional,
                        end = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                        path = "crl"
                    },
                new { start = @"\d+", end = @"\d+" }
                );  

            routes.MapRoute(
                "",
                "Source/Changeset/{start}/{*path}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Source",
                    action = "Changeset",
                    start = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    path = "crl"
                },
                new { start = @"\d+" }
                );  

            routes.MapRoute(
                "",
                "Source/Changeset/{*path}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Source",
                    action = "Changeset",
                    path = "crl"
                }
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are going to need to make routes for all possible combinations, which can get a little hairy:

```
//route if everything is included
routes.MapRoute(null, ""Source/Changeset/{start}/{end}/{*path}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

//route if nothing is included
routes.MapRoute(null, ""Source/Changeset/{*path}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", start=0, end=5 } //defaults
);

//and so on...
```

But, there is also a problem here: since *start* and *end* are both digits, there would be no way (since they are optional) to decide if the '2' in **Source/Changeset/2/fodass** is the *start* or *end* variable, so you may have to think up a new approach, or change yours to something like **Source/Changeset/Start/2/fodass**, **Source/Changeset/End/5/fodass**, **Source/Changeset/Start/2/End/5/fodass**, etc.

Comment: if a value exists, it's the start, so no need to do that. thank you for your help.